# export and import users and database collation issue

Tags: mysql, database, unicode, utf-8, collation

I have mambo 4.6.5 on my source site and joomla 1.5 on destination site. I'm going to move users from first one to second. so I install [**userport component**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/users-import-a-export/5430) on joomla 1.5 and then went to mambo database and select my users with this Query :

```
SELECT name, username, email, password FROM mos_users
```

and export them to a CSV file which is all "userport" needs.
some of user's name are Persian and UTF-8 . as you see in below some of texts are disassemble due to UTF-8 unicode while they have shown correctly in Backend and frontend section of mambo.
[mambo Database http://i.imagehost.org/0422/2_5.jpg](http://i.imagehost.org/0422/2_5.jpg)
(mambo database)

The problems is here :
when i import my users in joomla 1.5 via userport, the texts that seems disassemble in database (***But shows correctly in mambo simultaneity !***) ; are as when shows in mambo database and remain ill in joomla administrator : 
[joomla Administrator http://i.imagehost.org/0675/1_34.jpg](http://i.imagehost.org/0675/1_34.jpg)
(joomla Administrator)

What's the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.j2trip.com/html/y2009/10/import-users-into-joomla.html